# php-aria2 JSONRPC Empty reply from server

Tags: rpc, json-rpc, aria2

I use [php-aria2](https://code.google.com/p/php-aria2/) to download remote files. But all request to `127.0.0.1:8100/jsonrpc` returns null. aria2c works fine from command line.

When I run this from command line

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/jsonrpc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --data '{{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id":1, "method": "aria2.getGlobalStat", "params":[]}' -G
```

I got:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Somebody  knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is remove redundant "{" and use POST instead of GET:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/jsonrpc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id":1, "method": "aria2.getGlobalStat", "params":[]}'
```

aria2 supports JSON-RPC in GET request, but it needs to be encoded properly. See http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#json-rpc-using-http-get

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"qwer","method":"aria2.getGlobalStat", "params": []}' http://localhost:6800/jsonrpc
```

if us --rpc-secret=TOKEN need this

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"qwer","method":"aria2.getGlobalStat", "params": ["token:TOKEN"]}' http://localhost:6800/jsonrpc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/jsonrpc --data "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\"id\":1, \"method\": \"aria2.getGlobalStat\", \"params\":[]}"
```

or

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/jsonrpc --data "{"""jsonrpc""": """2.0""","""id""":1, """method""": """aria2.getGlobalStat""", """params""":[]}"
```